# Conditional binding (property of two-dimensional list)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have two-dimensional list of pages (ViewModels) to create on screen matrix of buttons

```
public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<ViewModelPageBase>> Pages { get; private set; }
```

Each page have `IsError` dependency property, implemented in their base class `ViewModelPageBase`. If `IsError` is set, then text of corresponding button become `Red`. Everything works fine until here.

Now I want following:

- if any of ViewModels `IsError` is set, then set panel, hosting buttons, background to `Yellow`.

I could scan all pages every time something is changed (`INotifyCollectionChanged. CollectionChanged`), to check if one of them has `IsError = true` and have separate dependency property to be set, then bind to this property to change panel background.

But I was thinking, maybe there is a way to bind to `IsError` directly? Is it possible? And if not, what is right solution to achieve needed?

---

Here is how `List<List<T>>` is visualized into matrix of buttons

```
<!-- how to change color of ItemControl to Yellow, when item IsError is set? -->
<!-- rows -->
<ItemControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemContainerTemplate>
            <!-- columns -->
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemContainerTemplate>
                        <!-- item -->
                        <!-- binding IsError to change button color works ok -->
                        <Button ... />
                    </ItemContainerTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ItemContainerTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: What do you have so far? Can you include your Xaml?

Comment: From what I can tell your itemcontainertemplate has only a button, if you put the button inside a a layout element(e.g. a grid) you could bind it's background property. Sounds right?